# Do all conjuration (teleportation) spells end your turn?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

From the description of [Dimension Door](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dimensionDoor.htm):

> After using this spell, you can’t take any other actions until your next turn.

Does this only apply to the spellcaster? If the caster brings along one or more willing creatures, then can they still have their full action in the same round that they appear? What about ready/hold an action?

Also, I would like to know whether or not this same restriction applies to other [conjuration (teleportation)](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#teleportation) spells such as [Greater Teleport](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleportGreater.htm) or [Refuge](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/refuge.htm)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By RAW, no, it doesn't affect other creatures, though as a GM I have ruled that it does because I believe that's the spirit of that part of the spell (disorientation due to the dimensional movement, often part of teleportation in fiction).

And as the effect is not listed in other spells, it does not affect other spells. Though if you wanted to add it in, IMO it wouldn't be a bad idea, as all it would do is slightly hinder already cheesy "scry and die" attack routines.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the prior comment in that it is not explicitly written and to use the letter of the rule ("**you** can't") it would not affect others.  However, as a DM if you feel there is too much abuse you could always say that additional travelers must spend a simple action to act in the same round as a dimension door.

Comment: What is a "simple action?" And if you mean standard action, well you have to use an action to act right?  Do you mean that basically they'd get a move action?

Comment: Yes, a "Standard Action" is what I meant - sorry about the crossover of terminology.  And typically when I've played, a standard action could be used as a move action or one attack if you have more than one to your character, so using the "move" action to recover or the potential effectual action would be viable after but only one of the two.